Viewport render vs Final rendering differences using glare node?
This is what I see in the viewport

vs the final render

as you can see the final render doesn't have the glowey effect that should be there from the glare, I can see it in viewport as I have the render composition always feature on why is there a mismatch between my final render vs the viewport render?

Hello could you please share your file?
